# python: creating random values by excluding specific values from list

Tags: python, numpy, random

Assuming I have the following data:

```
data = [1,1,3,2,4]
max_value = 4 # it is known from before
number_of_random_values = 2
```

And what I want is to create random values with range between 1 and 4 for each point of `data` but excluding the case of the point for each case. To make it more clear here is an example:

```
data point    random_values
1          -> [2,4]
1          -> [3,2]
3          -> [1,4]
2          -> [3,1]
4          -> [1,3]
```

So what we have above is: for each data point two random values which these random numbers can not be the same as the data point. What I have done until now is the following:

```
desired_values = np.zeros((len(data), number_of_random_values))
range_of_data = range(1, max_value + 1)
i = 0
for data_point in data:
    copy_of_range = copy.copy(range_of_data)
    copy_of_range.remove(data_point)
    random_values_for_data_point = random.sample(copy_of_range, number_of_random_values)
    desired_values[i] = random_values_for_data_point
    i = i + 1
```

The above code does what I want (desired results in numpy array) but it is clear that it is not performance-wise optimized.

Is there a vectorized method to implement this?or something more efficient?

**Edit**

replacing `data` with

```
data = np.random.random_integers(max_value, size=(1000, 1)).tolist()
```

and running my solution among with the solutions from the answers below with:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()    
for _ in range(10000):
    # each solution
        .
        .
        .
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time - start_time)
```

we have the following results:

- my solution: 40.3 sec
- Anton vBR solution: 31.7 sec
- Desire: 261 sec

Answer (score 3):

If we don't use np for the random numbers,
 we can make something simple like this:

```
import random
import numpy as np

data = [1,1,3,2,4]
max_value = 4 # it is known from before
number_of_random_values = 2

output = [random.sample([i for i in range(1,max_value+1) if i != item],2)\
          for item in data]

np.array(output)
```

Returns

```
array([[4, 2],
   [3, 4],
   [1, 4],
   [1, 3],
   [3, 2]])
```

Comment: @Desire It is more **efficient** and it is simpler.

Comment: you dont have to create a list out of the range inside the list comprehension `list(range(1,max_value+1))` -> `range(1,max_value+1)` for a slight boost as the range will be traversed only once

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding a given integer in the range [1, max_value] can be achieved with modular arithmetics, which is vectorized in NumPy:

1. Generate a random number in range(0, max_value-1) (so not including max_value or max_value-1).
2. Add it to the given, excluded number.
3. Take the remainder modulo max_value, and add 1.

The result is equally likely to be any number between 1 and max_value inclusive, except the excluded one. (Indeed, the only way to get excluded value would be to add max_value-1 at step 1, which is not allowed).

So the problem boils down to generating many samples from the same array (no exclusion), *without replacement*. Unfortunately it does not seem like NumPy has a tool for this at present. The method [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice) only produces one sample, so one has to call it in a loop.

```
data = np.array([1,1,3,2,4])
max_value = 4
number_of_random_values = 2

desired_values = np.zeros((len(data), number_of_random_values), dtype=np.int)
for i in range(len(data)):
    desired_values[i, :] = np.random.choice(max_value-1, number_of_random_values, replace=False)
desired_values = np.mod(desired_values + data.reshape(-1, 1), max_value) + 1
```

Notice this version declares dtype of array `desired_data`, which would be float64 by default. The type could be `np.int8` if you expect only small integers.

Comment: however from the timings it be seen that it doesn't scale. (mistakenly before i posted wrong timing)